# Convert base64 string to file without saving it to memory? - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, appsweep

I have a base64 string and I want to open the correspondent file generated from this string, but without saving it to the phone's storage.

Initially, I have created a file from this base64 string and saved it to temporary storage, then open it, using open_file plugin from Flutter. But after I upload the .apk to AppSweep, it returns the following issue: Insecure file location is retrieved via getExternalMediaDirs. I have observed that the issue comes from the open_file library. Is there any other solution?

```
  Uint8List buffer = base64Decode(fileContent);

  final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();

  int lastDotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
  String formattedFileName = fileName.substring(0, lastDotIndex);
  String extension = fileName.substring(lastDotIndex + 1);

  File file = File(
      "${directory!.path}/${formattedFileName}.$extension");

  await file.writeAsBytes(buffer);
  await OpenFile.open(file.path);
```

Comment: Strange story. If you have an encoded file in a base64 string in memory then you can decode the string to the bytes of the file in memory and then save those bytes from memory to storage so you have a nice file again.

Comment: Are you mixing up memory with storage?

Comment: I have edited the question, I don't want to save it to storage. For the base64 string I am calling an HTTP request, I receive the base64 string and after that I want to open the correspondent file. Is it clear now?

Comment: I want to convert that data into a file and open it. My question was how can I open the file such that the issue with the getExternalMediaDirs doesn't appear anymore? I have used getTemporaryDirectory().

Comment: `I receive the base64 string and after that I want to open the correspondent file. Is it clear now?` No. As if you want to open a file like you do then you should have a file to begin with. And files reside in storage.

Comment: You better tell what you wanna do with the 'file' as maybe there is a simple solution.

Comment: `I have edited the question,` You should also edit the subject of your post.

Comment: If you just need an input stream for the decoded bytes to read from the stream then just tell.

Comment: I don't know how to save the file in storage without calling android.content.Context.getExternalMediaDirs(). This is called when opening the file.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue `Insecure file location is retrieved via getExternalMediaDirs` only appears if your app calls `android.content.Context.getExternalMediaDirs()`.

This is because those locations are not particularly secure see [Android Docu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalMediaDirs()):

> These directories still exist and are scanned, but developers are encouraged to migrate to inserting content into a MediaStore collection directly, as any app can contribute new media to MediaStore with no permissions required, starting in Build.VERSION_CODES.Q.

The only file-related API you are using is `getTemporaryDirectory`, but that does not seem to store in the media dir, so I don't think this call is the reason for this finding.

Typically, AppSweep shows you the exact location and a code snippet of what it finds, does that help you to investigate the problem more?

Btw, if you want direct help in AppSweep, feel free to use the chat on the bottom right, then you can talk to one of the AppSweep team (e.g. me) directly.

Comment: The problem is from the OpenFile.open(file.path), where I am using open_file package from Flutter. If I am not using this package anymore, the issue disappears. Also, the location returned by AppSweep is androidx.core.content.FileProvider$Api21Impl.